# mysql error code 1064 where statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to SQL/MYSQL and I am having a problem…I created a database with tables and such and I can search it no problem…however when I add in a `"WHERE"` statement, I get the `error code 1064`. any help would be appreciated.

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE salary =>60000' at line 1
```

My query is this…

```
SELECT 
    salary
FROM
    instructor; 
WHERE 
    salary => 60000
```

If I run the query without the `"WHERE"` line it works just fine, but with it i get that error above. also, just to note, the word `"WHERE"` IS UNDERLINED IN RED, BUT NO OTHER WORDS ARE.

thanks for any help!
also, I'm using mysql workbench version 5.2.47 on a mac

Comment: move that semicolon to the end of the line.

Comment: im an idiot…and you are a god!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT salary FROM instructor; WHERE salary =>60000
```

you have an added ';' before the WHERE. That could be causing the issue.

It should instead be:

```
SELECT salary from instructor WHERE salary => 60000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon will terminate the SQL statement so anything typed after the semicolon is considered to be a new statement.
Since starting a query with a WHERE keyword is syntactically incorrect, the WHERE clause was underlined.

SELECT salary FROM instructor; WHERE salary => 60000

> SELECT salary FROM instructor;

is a statement by itself without the where clause.
However,

> WHERE salary => 60000

does not make any sense to the system hence is marked by the editor.